# Anorm with SQL expressions as parameter values

Tags: scala, anorm

I am trying to create this SQL statement with Anorm in Scala. I am using a Postgres DB.

```
insert into my_table (coords) values (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(26.9484 24.03937)',4326)
```

I have tried this code:

```
val lat = 26.9484
val long = 24.03937
val coords = s"ST_GeomFromText('POINT($lat $long)',4326)"
SQL"insert into my_table (coords) values (${coords})".executeInsert()
```

But I get this error:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: subfield "coords" is of type geometry but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

```
val lat = Some(26.9484)
val long = Some(24.03937)
SQL"insert into my_table (coords) values (ST_MakePoint(${lat}, ${long}))".executeInsert()
```

Nice benefit is that if lat or long are None (null) then the coords field is set to NULL in the table.

Comment: Using `Some(..)` is useless.